# Definition of elliptic system of PDEs - question in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

I was reading about elliptic systems of PDEs, say of order $2$. From different sources I found a few seemingly different definitions. Here is the setting:

Assume we have $N\times N$ many $n\times n$ matrices, we call these matrices $A^{\alpha\beta}$ with $1\leq \alpha, \beta\leq N$; denote by $A^{\alpha\beta}_{ij}$ the $(i, j)$-entry of $A^{\alpha\beta}$. We assume
$A^{\alpha\beta}_{ij}=A^{\beta\alpha}_{ij}=A^{\alpha\beta}_{ji}$. Consider the differential operator $P$ that maps the vector valued function $(u_1, ..., u_N)$ on ${\mathbb R}^n$ to the vector valued function $(A^{\alpha\beta}_{ij}\partial_i\partial_ju_\beta)_{1\leq \alpha\leq N}$ on ${\mathbb R}^n$. Here repeated index means summation.

Consider the following conditions:

1. There is $c>0$ so that for any $N$ many $n$-vectors $\xi_1, ..., \xi_N$, we have $A_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}\xi_\alpha^i\xi_\beta^j>c|\xi|^2=c\sum_{\gamma, k}|\xi_\gamma^k|^2$; here $\xi_\gamma^k$ is the $k$-th entry in the $n$-vector $\xi_\gamma$. This condition appears in several papers & books.
2. For any $n$-vector $\xi\neq 0$ the $N\times N$ matrix $(A^{\alpha\beta}_{ij}\xi^i\xi^j)_{1\leq \alpha, \beta\leq N}$ is positive definite, $(A^{\alpha\beta}_{ij}\xi^i\xi^j)_{1\leq \alpha, \beta\leq N}\geq c|\xi|^2I_N$. This means for any $t_1, t_2, ..., t_N$ we have $A_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}t_\alpha t_\beta\xi^i\xi^j>c|\xi|^2\cdot|t|^2$. This is the condition that the differential operator $P$ being "strongly elliptic". See e.g. Taylor's PDE book.
3. For any $n$-vector $\xi\neq 0$ the $N\times N$ matrix $(A^{\alpha\beta}_{ij}\xi^i\xi^j)_{1\leq \alpha, \beta\leq N}$ is nonsingular. This is the classical condition for the differential operator $P$ being "elliptic".

Clearly condition 1 implies condition 2, which then implies condition 3. My question is, can condition 2 imply condition 1? And is there any hope condition 3 also implies conditions 1, 2?